# not equal between two literally same CGAL::Point_3 points

Tags: equals, intersection, point, cgal, segment

I have two collinear CGAL::Segment_3 segments i and j:

```
i: -5.75 0 0 -9.05 0 0, j: -8.77 0 0 -5.75 0 0.
```

I computed their intersection using `CGAL::intersection()` and I got the result which is also a segment:

```
s: -8.77 0 0 -5.75 0 0.
```

Then compared `i.source()` with `s.target()` which should be equal (i.e. 1 returned).

However, I got 0 returned.Can anyone tell me why this happened?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRL6z.png)

Answer (score 0):

Without any code to reproduce it is hard to tell precisely what is going on but most probably I would say that you are using a Kernel with inexact constructions.
If you use `CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel` as kernel, everything should be fine.

See also this [FAQ entry](https://www.cgal.org/FAQ.html#inexact_NT)